# Setting axios timeout value has no effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, coverity

we have set the timeout in the code like

```
    axios.defaults.timeout === 3000;
......
 try {
        const aData = await axios.get(Url, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': authToken.authHeaderValue,
            },
            httpAgent: new https.Agent({
                keepAlive: true
            }),
        });
....
```

However in the static code analysis(polaris synopsis) test it shows as

```
Discarding the result of operator "===" in "axios.defaults.timeout === 3000". What was this code intended to accomplish?
```

Is this setting or assignment of the variable discarded?

Comment: Instead of doing that you can use setTimeout function and inside that you can call add your axios code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`===` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) in Javascript is a boolean test, not an assignment.  The line of code:

```
axios.defaults.timeout === 3000;
```

has no effect.  Presumably, it was intended to *set* `timeout`, for example:

```
axios.defaults.timeout = 3000;
```

The erroneous syntax in question, using `===`, evidently (from a comment) comes from a medium.com article (blog) by Ekebor Kelechi, [Axios.defaults.timeout](https://kelechiekebor.medium.com/axios-defaults-timeout-4803b93d076d).  That article obviously has a mistake, intending to use `=`, as `===` by itself never has an effect in Javascript.

Comment: i referred to this post. https://kelechiekebor.medium.com/axios-defaults-timeout-4803b93d076d. to set the timeout

Comment: @reachjaango The article is mistaken.  I have updated my answer to mention it.